# selenium with unittest in the same window

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing

I'd like to do two tests with selenium and a unit test. The first one is done correctly, while the second one I would like to do after the first(continue) one in the same browser window.

How can I do this?

Thank you in advance for your time.

The code below generates an error in the second test because I did not initiate the browser window.

````
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
from sample.page.mainpage import MainPage

class uwaga(unittest.TestCase):
        @classmethod
        def setUpClass(cls):
            cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome("chrome/chromedriver")
            cls.driver.implicitly_wait(3)
            cls.driver.maximize_window()


        def test_open_article_add(self):
            driver = self.driver
            driver.get("http://localhost")
            main = MainPage(driver)
            main.click_mainlink)
            main.click_submenu()
            main.click_button_main_new()
            driver.find_element_by_name('test').send_keys('dupa')

        def test_open_article2(self):

            driver.find_element_by_name('test').send_keys('test2')```
````

Comment: Can you post the full error message please? Also, you're referencing `driver`, but it should be `self.driver` in `test_open_article2`.

Comment: I might see what your problem is without the error. You can't assume the tests will run in the order they are listed in the class -- they run in alphabetical order. You're also assuming that assigning driver will survive between functions -- that assignment is scoped to that single test case function.

Comment: Thx, the problem was in the self.driver. I spent an hour looking for the cause, and it was trivial.